# Using Doctrine EntityManager inside PHPUnit test class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit

I can not access my Doctrine EntityManager inside my PHPUnit test class. I really don't understand, and I'm not using Symfony.

My UtilisateurService.php class :

```
<?php 

require_once './bootstrap.php';

class UtilisateurServices{
    
    private Utilisateur $_user;
    
    /**
     * Constructeur de classe.
     * @param integer $id identifiant généré de l'utilisateur
     */
    public function __construct($id){      
        $userRepo = $entityManager->getRepository("Utilisateur");
        $this->_user = $userRepo->find($id);
    } ...
```

My UtilisateurServiceTest.php :

```
<?php

class UtilisateurServicesTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase{

    /**
     *
     * @var UtilisateurServices
     */
    private $utilisateurServices;
        
    /**
     * Tests UtilisateurServices->getUtilisateur()
     */
    public function testGetUtilisateur()
    {
        
        $id = 1;
        $this->utilisateurServices = new UtilisateurServices($id);
        assert($this->utilisateurServices->getUtilisateur()->getId(), $id);
    }...
```

My Bootstrap.php file :

```
<?php
// bootstrap
namespace DPTrace\Bootstrap;

require_once join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [__DIR__, 'vendor', 'autoload.php']);

use Doctrine\ORM\tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$entitiesPath = [
    join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [__DIR__, "src\\entities"])
];

$dbParams = array(
    'driver'    =>  'pdo_mysql',
    'host'      =>  'localhost',
    'user'      =>  'DPTrace_test',
    'password'  =>  'test',
    'dbname'    =>  'DPTrace',
    'charset'   =>  'utf8'
);

$isDevMode = true;
$proxyDir = null;
$cache = null;
$useSimpleAnnotationReader = false;

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entitiesPath, $isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache, $useSimpleAnnotationReader);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

return $entityManager;

?>
```

The error message when I execute vendor\bin\phpunit tests/UtilisateurServicesTest.php -c tests/phpunit.xml

1. UtilisateurServicesTest::testGetUtilisateur
   Undefined variable: entityManager

C:\Users\gillian\git\repo\DPTrace\src\services\UtilisateurServices.php:20
C:\Users\gillian\git\repo\DPTrace\tests\UtilisateurServicesTest.php:26

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Why do you think `$entityManager` is available inside the constructor? I can't see it injected on instantiated or anything. Also, that doesn't seem to be related to phpunit.

Comment: So I should inject it in my constructor like __Construct(EntityManager $em) ? Just this ?

Comment: That declares it as a constructor argument. You need more, you need an instance. With symfony (and auto-wiring) declaring it in the constructor would be enough. Symfony would take care of the rest. Without symfony you'll have to create an instance yourself to be able to hand it over to your `UtilisateurServices`. Somewhere in your application you need a `new EntityManager(...)`. Maybe you want to do that at the same place you call `new UtilisateurServices(...)`. I won't be able to guide you through that. Probably you need to read up a few basic about working with doctrine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, when I copied/pasted the code from my IDE, I forget the "require_once './bootstrap.php'. In my bootstrap file, the entityManager is already instanciated, but for a reason I can not understand, I can't use it in my test class

Comment: But you haven't required the `bootstrap.php` from your test class, so the `$entityManager` doesn't exist

Comment: well, your `$entityManager` from bootstrap.php file is a global variable, it is not directly accessible from the constructor of `UtilisateurServices`.